# How to hide very large size folder or even a partition in windows 7 x64 in undiscoverable way?

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, user-folders

How to hide the very large folder with size near 70 GB in windows 7 x64 and also a partition d for example. so is there a way which the folder will be undiscoverable in, I think with such this way I need to chage the size indecator of the partition containing that large size hidden folder to make the operation realistic ?

Comment: You want to fake to smaller disk size?
What scenarios of discovering You assume?
Bulletproof way is hide it by steganograpy in huge video (aboit 1 TB).

Comment: yes, I assume that there might be an advanced or expert one who could search my pc, which video you mention about? thank you

Comment: You can do this with the standard Users permissions.  If a user does not have permissions to read the contents of a folder, then they are unable to determine the size of the contents, nor view its contents.

Comment: An "advanced or expert" cannot be fooled by trickery.

Comment: what about a folder?

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=steganography+video

Answer (score 2):

There's no such thing as "undiscoverable", but you can make it so that reasonable searches won't find it.  For instance, you can partition the hard drive (hiding items on it from completely new users), and then make the partition invisible (hiding it from any casual search).  It's a common practice for PC manufacturers to put the restore software on a separate partition, and some of them make the partition invisible so that users don't mess with it.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a truecrypt hidden volume.